# Trying to build a package in R.

Tags: r, shell, command-line, cran

I am trying to install a package from github. But my mac is telling me I need additional build tools. It then takes me to a web page. 
I simply want to install blotter

```
 library(devtools)
 install_github("braverock/blotter")
 install_github("braverock/FinancialInstrument")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some packages may require compilers to work (mostly for code in C/C++).

Comment: Try running `xcode-select --install` from a terminal - it will install some developer tools including C/C++